# Disable link_to tag in Rails3+

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used the following code:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("edit.png", :alt => "Edit"), edit_user_path(user) %>
```

I want to disable this link and image, so I added `:disabled=>true` to the code, but it's not disabling. Why not, and how do I disable them?

Comment: Since questions and answers are all down voted then I'm figuring that this is the wrong approach. Can anyone, with more experience, suggest why everything was down voted?

Comment: Can't say why voted down, but probably because they are not *easy* answers.  Disabled does not disable hyperlinks -- http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-87355129  So you will either need a conditional link or JavaScript to do the disabling

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what @lamrin wanted with this question, but I suppose that it is something like this:

```
<%= link_to_if condition?, image_tag("edit.png", :alt => "Edit"), edit_user_path(user) %>
```

With this code above, the image would have a link if the condition? is true

In my case this code below worked (a more complicated example):

```
link_to_unless disabled, (content_tag :div, "", :class => "vote " + vote_class, :title => title), resource_user_path({ :id => resuser.id, :resource_user => {:id => resuser.id, :resource_id => resource_id, :user_id => current_user_id, :vote => vote_value}}), :remote => true, :method => http_method
```

This link may also help with this approach:

http://railskey.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/rails-link_to-link_to_if-and-link_to_unless/

Answer (score 9):

Unlike buttons, hyperlinks cannot be "disabled". You can do the following though, assuming you have jQuery included on your pages:

```
<%=link_to image_tag("edit.png", :alt=>"Edit"), edit_user_path(user), :id => "mylink" %>
```

Add the following Javascript to your page:

```
$('#mylink').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: took this to disable all disabled links -- $('a[disabled]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your question, there is no :disabled option for the link_to helper in Rails, and it is not a valid attribute for a elements either. I believe the reason people tend to get confused with this in Rails is that ":disabled => true" does work IF you are using Bootstrap. So to fix this issue you can either follow Gupta's approach, or just add Bootstrap (which will give you some default CSS as well, so people don't get frustrated trying to click the link)!

Re: link_to method in rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Re: the "disabled" attribute on a elements: [Is 'disabled' a valid attribute for an anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711317/is-disabled-a-valid-attribute-for-an-anchor-tag)

Re: Bootstrap "disabled" class or attribute with bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#anchor-element-1

Comment: @lamrin, did this answer your question? You are using Ruby on Rails, and just wanting to be able to add ":disabled => true" to this code, right? Let me know if there is anything you still need help with!

Comment: The reference to valid attributes on anchor tag is really helpful!

Comment: Glad it was helpful @SergioA.! Here is the updated reference for Bootstrap 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/buttons/#disabled-state

Answer (score 0):

1)One solution is to render just image_tag when you do not want link and use link_to when u want link to be click enabled. you can use instance variables to control what to render.

2) or use Javascript as suggested.

Use 2 if you want to dynamically do it.

Answer (score -2):

You may use conditional link_to:

```
<%=
 link_to_if(@current_user.nil?, "Login", { :controller => "sessions", :action => "new" }) do
   link_to(@current_user.login, { :controller => "accounts", :action => "show", :id => @current_user })
 end
%>
```