# HTML <a> download Attribute

Tags: json, html, angularjs

I wanted to know how to disable the "download" attribute for an anchor tag like download="false" :

```
<a href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/HTML5/512/HTML_Logo.png" download></a>
```

I have an application built using angularjs and the interaction I am expecting to build is, all image files can be viewed but any non-image file will be downloaded

I am unable to print the value of my json "downloadable" parameter using angular, I have a json which contains parameter that determines if a file is downloadable or not, if its downloadable then "downloadable":"download" and if the file is not downloadable which means it is an image file it may simply be viewed in the browser, in that case I set "downloadable":"" and my anchor code is

```
<a href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/HTML5/512/HTML_Logo.png" {{downloadable}}></a>
```

this does not print "download" in place of "downloadable", but if I try the following code

```
<a href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/HTML5/512/HTML_Logo.png" data={{downloadable}}>
```

it gets rendered as expected i.e

```
<a href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/HTML5/512/HTML_Logo.png" data="download"></a>
```

Comment: just don't use this attribute, or remove it from your anchor tag with JavaScript

Comment: Probably more correct to use data-* attributes as intended. Try data-downloadable="true".

Comment: I have all my files in a json and using angularjs ng-repeat i ab printing the html, yes I can write additional script to remove it, but I wanted to either print the attribute download if its downloadable or print nothing if its not. This could be done at the same time while ng-repeat works on my array just that angular is unable to render the json value as pointed in my explanation above

Comment: you have to do what ng-disable does.. add/remove attribute based on boolean condition

Comment: I don't understand how your json cannot be read by AngularJS.
Plus, for syntax reasons, you should have your downloadable attribute revised : "download": true or false
Also you can check this link if you want to create a directive : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711317/is-disabled-a-valid-attribute-for-an-anchor-tag

Answer (score -1):

Probably more correct to use data-* attributes as intended. Try data-downloadable="true". But if you want the resource to be downloadable you have to host them yourself. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a . You can't offer download of other people's resources.