# BookYourSeats: How to Disable the link once the counter reaches zero in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frameworks, frontend

I am in the middle of creating an app that helps you to book your seats.

[image: This is the interface of my seat layout]

My problem is that I cannot disable the selecting of seats once the selectedVal reaches zero.

```
<a class="available" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-class="{'selected': item.check == true,'available': item.check == false}" ng-click="execute($index,$parent.$index,item.val,item.letter)">{{item.val}}</a>
```

**States of the Seats:**

There are 3 States (CSS Rules)

1. Available - In this the Users can select the seats(changing the seat color and backgroundColor on hover).
2. Selected - In this the Seat backgroundColor: blue and the color: white.
3. Blocked - In this the Seat backgroundColor: grey and the color: white and the user cursor changes from pointer to default.

What the User Can Do (**User Cases**)?

1. Select and Deselect the Seats with respect to the selectedVal, i.e if the 
   selectedVal = 4 then the user can select only 4 seats in total.
2. if the SelectedVal is less than 1 then the user should not be able
   to select the seat anymore unless the user deselect any of the
   previously selected seats and select again.
3. Booked Seats Case: If the check value of a seat is true, then the
   user should not be able to select or deselect that seat(a.blocked
   CSS rule is Added for that purpose) since it is already selected by
   another user(Lets assume).

**Additional UI Cases**

**Collective Automatic Seat Selection**

Once goto this link: in.bookmyshow.com/buytickets/me-before-you-national-capital-region-ncr/movie-ncr-ET00035678-MT/20160612#!seatlayout. and try to book some seats, you can notice that if the total seat quantity = 3 then at the seatLayout page when the user clicks on one seat the next two seats are also selected automatically.
[Ref Img: BookMyShow SeatLayout and selection process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcpWg.png)

Code Source: https://jsfiddle.net/rittamdebnath/5vqxgtq3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a logic like this in execute function:

```
$scope.execute = function(i, j, itemVal, itemLetter) {
  angular.forEach($scope.obj, function(v, k) {
    if (v[i].val == itemVal && v[i].letter == itemLetter) {

      if ($scope.isDisabled && v[i].check == false) 
        return;

      v[i].check = !v[i].check;
      if (v[i].check)
        $scope.selectedVal -= 1;
      else
        $scope.selectedVal += 1;

      console.log(itemVal + " " + itemLetter);
      if ($scope.selectedVal < 1) {
        $scope.isDisabled = true;
      } else {
        $scope.isDisabled = false;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I've added this extra if condition:

```
if ($scope.isDisabled && v[i].check == false) 
  return;
```

I hope this will help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thankyou for the help. but Let's say that i have an object whose check == true. then the seat must be blocked , ie the user should not be able to select or deselect the seat. I've included a class in the CSS **a.blocked** to show that the seat is already been booked

Comment: Can you help me with the additional UI Cases

Answer (score 0):

> Disabled is not a valid attribute for the anchor tag. Source : http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-a-element

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/18711335/4989081)

You can use button instead:

```
<button class="available" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-class="{'selected': item.check == true,'available': item.check == false}" ng-click="execute($index,$parent.$index,item.val,item.letter)">{{item.val}}</button>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/odsyea33/

Selected seats can be marked off using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `ng-disabled` with `<a>`. It wont work.

You can use lazy evaluation inside your  `ng-click` as a workaround in this case:

```
ng-click="(isDisabled && item.check != true) || execute($index,$parent.$index,item.val,item.letter)"
```

Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vqxgtq3/5/).

Comment: i should also be able to deselect the seat and again select another.