# Why do my circular buttons break when going from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/b3x6ou4k/

When I change the CSS link from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4 (using https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css as the CSS), the circle buttons change to square.

Why does the CSS for circular buttons:

```
.btn-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

not work in Bootstrap 4 and how do I keep this style:

[image]

rather than this style:

[image]

when upgrading from 3 to 4?

Comment: Check the docs. With a major version bump api changes are likely to break things. See if they have a migration document.

Comment: I see circular buttons (no connecting lines) - what browser(s) are you seeing this in? Also, you probably want to use the latest 4.x version, which is 4.3.1 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to consult the [migration docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/), but this seems to approximate what you had before: https://jsfiddle.net/xrcu92bo/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="stepwizard">
        <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
            <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3"> 
                <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle">1</a>
                <p><small>Shipper</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3"> 
                <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn border btn-light btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
                <p><small>Destination</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3"> 
                <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn border btn-light btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
                <p><small>Schedule</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3"> 
                <a href="#step-4" type="button" class="btn border btn-light btn-circle" disabled="disabled">4</a>
                <p><small>Cargo</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form role="form">
        <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-1">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title">Shipper</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-2">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title">Destination</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-3">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title">Schedule</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-4">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title">Cargo</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit">Finish!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Basically, `.btn-default` doesn't exist in Bootstrap 4; the closest you get is `.btn-light`. I also added the `.border` class, since the light button doesn't have a lot of contrast with your background.

Also, the `disabled` property [doesn't actually do anything on an anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711317/is-disabled-a-valid-attribute-for-an-anchor-tag) - you'll want to use the `disabled` class if you want to prevent users from clicking on "disabled" steps.