# After <a> onclick, wait the function to be completed and then click/process again

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm using `jQuery.get` to do an AJAX request. When the user clicks on the `<a>`, I am sending a request to server via `jQuery.get`, and then update the `<div id='aaa'>ajax call back here</a>`;

However, when the user clicks on `<a>` very fast, the return data slower then clicking, and `<div id ='aaa'></a>` does not match with what is stored in the database.

For example `<div id='aaa'>10</div>`, -1 when user click 1 time. User clicks 5 times, and `#aaa` is supposed to be `<div id='aaa'>5</div>`, but since the user clicked very fast, the div shows `<div id='aaa'>8</div>`. Server database has been update to `5` and when the user clicks 1 more time, the `<div id='aaa'>8</div>` will be turned to `<div id='aaa'>4</a>` because the server side is `5`.

I know this is about AJAX network request will take some finite time.

So, is it possible my function wait until the `jQuery.get` done and complete, then only able to click/process again. I have try the below coding, but still same problem with above mention.

```js
var isPending = false

function fastbtn(sid, t) {
  if (isPending)
    return;
  goodget('', 'plugin.php?id=ttt&do=realland&ac=' + sid + '&click=true');
}

function goodget(url, rid) {
  isPending = true;
  jQuery.get(url, function(data, status) {
      ajaxget(rid); //this ajaxget is my program core template language, ajaxget(url,WaitId), return as XML format;
    })
    .done(function() { // <--only fires on success
      //alert('ok2');
    })
    .fail(function() { // <-- only fires on error

    })
    .always(function() { // <-- this always fires
      isPending = false;
    });
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="fastbtn('watering')">some div ...</a>
```

[image]

You will see the numbering is jumping..

Comment: You can disable the anchor element when the function `fastbtn()` is called and then re-enable it when the AJAX is over.

Comment: I trying this, but if the user clicks fast, since the `onclick` has been turn to blank, then the `<a onclick>` is not able to click until I refresh the webpage. `<a href="javascript:;" id="watering" onclick="fastbtn('watering');">`, `<script>
function fastbtn(sid, t){
 jQuery('#watering').attr('onclick','');
 ajaxget('plugin.php?id={$jn}&do=realland&ac='+sid+'&formhash={FORMHASH}','aaa');
}</script>`

Comment: You can also define `onclick` with jQuery, HTML is not necessary: `$(document).on('click', elem, function() { if (ajaxPending) { return; } else { fastbtn(args) } })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd replace `a` tag with `button` (since the purpose of `a` tags are navigation) and keep it disabled on click unless the server sends the response.

```
<button onclick="fastbtn('watering')">some div ...</button>
```

After the response is received, i.e, either success of failure, enable the button again.

```
var isPending = false

function fastbtn(sid, t) {
  if (isPending)
    return;
  goodget('', 'plugin.php?id=ttt&do=realland&ac=' + sid + '&click=true');
}

function goodget(url, rid) {
  isPending = true;
  $('button').attr("disabled", true)
  jQuery.get(url, function(data, status) {
      ajaxget(rid); //this ajaxget is my program core template language, ajaxget(url,WaitId), return as XML format;
    })
    .done(function() { // <--only fires on success

    })
    .fail(function() { // <-- only fires on error

    })
    .always(function() { // <-- this always fires
      isPending = false;
     $('button').attr("disabled", false)
    });
}
```

**EDIT**
Updating the answer after double-beep's inputs.

Comment: erm.. this function need to use which version jQuery? when I click on `fastbtn`, js error.. `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`, I am using jquery-1.7.2.min.js and ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js ..

Comment: `disabled` attribute is not valid for anchor tags - see https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-a-element, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18711317, etc. Try it with any `<a>`: you will see it won't work.

Comment: @SweeHong are you getting the error even with `$('a')`? Also I'd suggest you to use a button, since `a` tags are primary used for the purpose of navigation.

Comment: @double-beep hmm, right. So In this case I think we should use a `button` as the purpose of `a` is navigation anyway. Isn't it?

Comment: @SweeHong you can try now.

Comment: Obviously @SweeHong would need to update their code in order to use a `button` tag - I'd suggest that too. You only need `onclick` there.

Comment: thanks all, after i using `button` is work fine. I didn't using `button` before this because i need to stylist the `div`, what you see in the picture. Just now found that I can use `unset:all` to remove all button default style, so I think now I can use `button` to replace all the similar process.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `setTimeout`. So

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fastbtn('watering');">some div ...</a>

var isPendingTimeout = null;
function fastbtn(sid, t) {
  goodget('', 'plugin.php?id=ttt&do=realland&ac=' + sid + '&click=true');

  isPendingTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    if (isPending == true) {
       clearTimeout(isPendingTimeout);

       ---- do what you want ------
    } 
  }, 25);

  return false;

}
```

Hope it helps to solve your problem.

Comment: `setTimeout` might not be a good solution since you don't know what kind of time the server is gonna take to process and then send the response.